# header data render_to_response to include X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL

Tags: python, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I want to add `X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL` to the header of some page (for some remote ajax calls).

My view is simple, something like this:

```
def info(request):    
    return render_to_response("info.html",
                               locals(),
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I modify the header content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using render_to_response(), use render()

```
def info(request):
    data = render(request, 'info.html')
    response = HttpResponse(data)
    response['X-Frame-Options'] = "ALLOWALL"
    return response
```

And there's also the global setting. To use it, add this to Middleware:
`'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',` and add to the settings `X-Frame-Options = 'ALLOWALL'` , however that is usually not a good idea unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: You can simplify the answer by changing the second line to `response = render(request, 'info.html', locals())`, then removing the `HttpResponse` line.